# DataBinding is not working in my Controller

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, ionic-framework

I'm wondering why my DatBinding is not working.

The problem is in the function `foo` where the `$scope.data.time` is set properly but my `input-value` does not change. **Why?**

Here is the Code of my Controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $ionicPopup, $cordovaDatePicker) {    

    $scope.foo = function() {
        $cordovaDatePicker.show().then(function(date){
            // PROBLEM: the $scope.data is set right, but my input value does not change
            $scope.data.time = date;    
        });
    };

    $scope.showPopup = function() {
        $scope.data = {};
        $scope.data.time = new Date();

      var myPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
        template: '<input type="text" ng-click="foo()" value="{{data.time.toDateString()}}">'
        title: 'Enter new record',
        scope: $scope,
        ...
      });
     };

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set $ionicPopup scope to $scope after template.

Eg.

template : 'your template input',
scope : $scope

Comment: Can you give me a example in my code, I don't know how to make it

Comment: Do you just mean the scope: $scope part? I have this already in my code and added it to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself: the framework which I'm using is caching the site. So I needed to disable caching and now it work perfect.